# why is calculator.getValue() always 0?

Tags: java

I am a java student and I am working to make my code more object oriented. I can easily code calculator in main but I'm really struggling to implement it with methods. The following code will always return 0...but the goal is to create a program which allows a user to enter an operator and a number in one line (example +5) the code should output the previous value, the new value, and allow for resetting. I believe I am really close to solving this and just need a point in the right direction..

output

```
Enter an operator and a number:
+5
0.0
```

Calculator class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {
    private final int RESET = 0;
    private double number = 0;
    private double result = 0; // I believe this is the issue but how can I resolve it?
    private char operator;
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public Calculator(double number)
    {
        this.number = number;

    }
    // this method invokes the whatOperator() to create a new result
    // the edited method still returns 0
    public double aResult(Calculator other)
{

    other.whatOperator();
    this.result = other.result;
    return result;

} 
    // I created this method in hopes that it would do most of the work..when I invoke it and enter my operator and number it does not seem to function correctly
    public void whatOperator()
    {

        String operator = null;
        operator = enterNumber();
        double theNumber = Double.parseDouble(operator);
        char theOperator =operator.charAt(0);
        operator = null;
        operator += theOperator;

        // switch method to find the operator
        switch(operator){
        case "*":
        result = getNumber() * theNumber;
        break;
        case "/":
        result = getNumber() / theNumber;
        break;
        case "+":
        result = getNumber() + theNumber;
        break;
        case "-":
        result = getNumber() - theNumber;
        break;
        case "R":
        result = RESET;
        break;
    }


}
// methods for operation...I was hoping to not use these
public double add(double secondNumber)
{
    result = number + secondNumber;
    return result;

}
public double divide(double secondNumber)
{
    result = number / secondNumber;
    return result;
}
public double multiply(double secondNumber)
{
    result = number * secondNumber;
    return result;
}
public void subtract(double secondNumber)
{
    result = number - secondNumber;
}
public double getNumber()
{
    return number;
}
   // method for getting input
public static String enterNumber()
    {

        System.out.println("Enter an operator and a number:");
        String toString = keyboard.nextLine();
        return toString;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // the calculator is initialized at 0
        Calculator a = new Calculator(0);
        // now I create a second calculator with the result from the aResult()
        Calculator b = new Calculator(a.aResult(a));
        // why is b.getNumber() = 0 at this point?
        String theString = String.valueOf(b.getNumber());
       // prints 0 every time
        System.out.println(theString);




        }

    }
```

Comment: There's no `getNumber()` method in the code you've posted.

Comment: in aResult `this.result = result` does nothing, it should read `this.result = other.aResult()`

Comment: On a general note, it's very strange to create a new `Calculator` for each step of the calculation. There should only ever be one instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code.

```
public double aResult(Calculator other)
{
    other = new Calculator(getNumber());
    other.whatOperator();
    this.result = result;
    return result;

}
```

The line this.result = result doesn't make any sense. I think you wanted the method whatOperator() to return a result e.g.

```
this.result = other.whatOperator();
```

I also think that you don't want to override the "other" calculator. You never use the new calculator. But you want to print the output of the new calculator in your main method. Because you never used the new calculator, the output is 0.

Comment: whatOperator is void

Comment: that definitely makes sense. So I would then change the whatOperator() method to double?

Comment: yes, or do it like this. this.result = other.result

Answer (score 0):

In your aResult method you are initiating another new instance of Calculator

```
public double aResult(Calculator other) {
    //other = new Calculator(getNumber()); // this should not be here
    other.whatOperator();
    this.result = result;
    return result;

}
```

Comment: Yes the above comments had pointed that out...I corrected it but the output is the same

Comment: another correction in whatOperator method assign operator = "" before
        operator += theOperator; otherwise operator variable is assigned null+ and no switch condition met.

Comment: solved! I am unsure who to give credit to here, you guys all helped me out

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem:

```
//change
 this.result = result; //this does nothing 
 //to
 this.result = other.result; //this changes the result to the new value
//erase this line
other = new Calculator(getNumber()); // do not need to create a new calculator
```

change the method whatOperator to a double and return a double with it